# How to load images from PC to iOS 8 iPhone camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, pc

I have 100 pictures on my PC that I want to load into my Camera Roll. The PC is running Vista so I can't install iCloud onto it.

On iCloud.com, I only see Notes, Contacts, etc, but not Photos.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/m) or [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com/). I know Dropbox allows roughly 3GB (I think) for free and depending on the size of your photographs that may be enough.

All you do is login online and upload the photos to Dropbox (note that Cubby is comparable in nearly all aspects) and then install the app on your phone. You can then save the images to your camera roll.

Note that if you use [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/m/?mts=20141127065702) (if you don't now perhaps you should anyway), you can simply download the images from your app on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can email the picture to your your Apple ID email address. You can then open that email on your phone and add the picture to your camera roll from there.

Comment: Ah. I shouldn't have said image. It's 100 images. Any other idea?

Comment: For that amount of data I would recommend something like Dropbox, or similar, or Backblaze. I do know that both Dropbox and Backblaze have native iOS clients.

Answer (score 0):

By enabling **iCloud Photo Library** you can now visit https://www.icloud.com/photos and upload all your photos from there. Your iPhone will then automatically download your photos into its “Camera Roll.”

Since this only requires a web browser, it works even on unsupported operating systems like Windows Vista.

However this will also upload your photos from your iPhone to iCloud, which requires that you have enough iCloud Storage allowance to store all your photos in iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer seems to suggest solutions which involve manually saving photos. Additionally, this might not allow you to retain image metadata, such as when the picture you're transferring was taken. You may use iCloud Photo Library, but in some occasions (if the pictures are too big) you may not want to use up bandwidth uploading the photos to iCloud, and downloading them again.

In that case I'd recommend any of the myriad of Wifi photo transfer tools for iOS, such as [WiFi Photo Transfer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-photo-transfer/id380326191?mt=8). This allow you to locally but wirelessly transfer photos to your iOS device easily, and retain picture metadata. This is done via a web browser, so the source OS is non-specific.

Answer (score -1):

Get app called Documents, it’s free.
Once you have it go to Wifi Transfer and follow instructions.
It is easy to use.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.